# Elements of $C(K)^{**}$, do they have a name?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $K$ be a compact (Hausdorff) space, and let $C(K)$ be the Banach algebra of contunous functions on $K$ (with the usual $\sup$-norm). The [enveloping von Neumann algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enveloping+von+Neumann+algebra) of $C(K)$ is its second dual Banach space, $C(K)^{**}$.

Question:

> Is it possible that the elements of $C(K)^{**}$ have some special name?

*"Von Neuman generalized functions on $K$"*, or something like this... Or, maybe this algebra $C(K)^{**}$ has a special name... (excuse me my ignorance).

Answer (score 1):

Since $C(K)^{**}$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra, then it is of the form $C(\tilde{K})$ for some compact $\tilde{K}$. This compact sapce is called a hyper-Stonean envelope of $K$. More on this subject you can find in [Second duals of measure algebras. H.G. Dales, A.T.-M. Lau, D. Strauss.](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6hgd/preprints/Dissertatmeasurealgebrafinal.pdf)

Comment: Why is $\widetilde{K}$ called "envelope"? Isn't $\widetilde{K}$ mapped into $K$?

Comment: You should ask Dales et Co. By the way here is one more useful link for you http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60328/what-kind-of-completion-is-this